# Limit An Iteration By A Predicate

Tags: scala

I can generate a list of values by repeatedly applications of a function on the previously generated value as follows:

```
List.iterate(math.Pi, 3)(x => math.sin(2*x))

List[Double] = List(3.141592653589793, -2.4492935982947064E-16, -4.898587196589413E-16)
```

In this case, the iteration will stop when the length of the list is three. Is there a function in the collections library which will allow me to stop the iteration based on some predicate such as "stop generating the list when a particular value has been generated", instead of the length of the list? I am open to using Streams as well if they have any additional functionality already built-in which can solve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if such a thing is possible directly with lists, possibly because you could create a potential infinite number of values. That's why you need to provide a `len` parameter.

But yes, you can create a `Stream` that generates values followed by a `takeWhile`. If you know that the amount of values will hold into a list, you can add a `.toList` call.

```
scala> Stream.iterate(math.Pi)(x => math.sin(2*x)).takeWhile(_ > 0).toList
res0: List[Double] = List(3.141592653589793)
```

Comment: That'll do it. I just need to `force` the stream to generate all the values.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't want to write recurcive function, like

```
def f(i: Int, acc: List[Double] = List()): List[Double] = {
    val newVal = math.sin(2*i)
    if (newVal < 0) {
        newVal :: acc
    } else {
        f(i + 1, newVal :: acc)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for something in the library. If there wasn't I would have manufactured my own as you suggest.

Comment: Yes, solution of I.K. is better.